# I get error HTTP 404 when I want to access my app that I published in azure using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, web-services, azure

when I click the link to the published app I get this:

the default url to the app

[image]

but when I add /MyAPP to the url I get this:

http error 404

[image]

Any idea please?

Comment: Try to add www to your website in Azure portal this might work. check this link for similar query https://serverfault.com/questions/205154/war-deployed-in-tomcat-not-showing-up-at-url-getting-404-instead

Comment: Thank you for your answer, none of that worked for me :/

Comment: Check web.config whether specify default document, note use this in order

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="index.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: I didn't get what you mean exactly

Comment: I suggested you to check your web.config file.